# How to obtain the indicated order along the x axis in python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw points in the desired sequence along the x axis - `'2017-11-01-2', '2017-11-01-3', '2017-11-01-1', '2017-11-01-4 ',' 2017-11-01-5',` for example. But the `plot` function changes the order to alphabetical - `'2017-11-01-1', '2017-11-01-2', '2017-11-01-3', '2017-11-01-4 ',' 2017-11-01-5'`.

Is it possible to draw points along the x axis in the sequence I need?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x = ['2017-11-01-2', '2017-11-01-3', '2017-11-01-1', '2017-11-01-4', '2017-11-01-5'] # the order I need
y = ['1879994', '1879995', '1891647', '1889925', '1879900']

xax = ax.get_xaxis()

plt.title('Title')
plt.ylabel('PPS')
plt.xlabel('Date-Commit')
xlabels = xax.get_ticklabels()

for label in xlabels:
    label.set_rotation(45)

ax.plot(x, y, '-bo')
plt.savefig('chart.png', fmt='png')
plt.show()
```

[received chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKuqs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try having a dummy x-axis and using the dates that you require as just xticklabels

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = [1879994, 1879995, 1891647, 1889925, 1879900]
x = range(len(y))
ticklabels = ['2017-11-01-2', '2017-11-01-3', '2017-11-01-1', '2017-11-01-4', '2017-11-01-5']
plt.xticks(x, ticklabels)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanck you very much. Your crafty method helped me to solve the problem.